# How to install opencv in Docker?

Tags: python, docker, opencv

Here is a Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10

RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y libopencv-dev python3-opencv
```

I can open `bash` in that container:

```
$ docker  run -i -t  opencv /bin/bash
```

It installed Debian:

```
# cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 11 \n \l
```

It shows opencv 4.5.1:

```
# apt install python3-opencv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
python3-opencv is already the newest version (4.5.1+dfsg-5).
```

If I try to import cv2, it's not found:

```
# python3 -c "import cv2"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

If I ask `dpkg`, it says which files should be there:

```
# dpkg -L python3-opencv
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/python3
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cv2.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
...
```

and they are:

```
# ls -l /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cv2.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6757472 Jun 16  2021 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cv2.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
# which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

So .. what is missing?  How do I use the opencv that looks like it's been installed?  Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, it looks like there are two pythons.  The one in `/usr/bin` works.

```
# ls -l /usr/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Apr  5  2021 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.9
# ls -l /usr/local/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr  7 03:17 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> python3.10
# /usr/bin/python3 -c "import cv2"
#
```